# DNS Bind not loaded due to errors

Tags: linux, dns, bind

This is a school assignment and I'm having trouble with my DNS bind configuration. I'm supposed to setup a DNS server and I need to set SOA, NS and glue record, A records for www, mail and for the name server for the subdomain, and a CNAME.

I'm trying to setup a DNS server for the following domain: mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.

I have three different db files, mcduckcorp.db, duckburg.db and cali.db. I did a check with the command "named-checkzone" and here is the result:

mcduckcorp.db:

```
dns_master_load: /etc/bind/mcduckcorp.db:1: extra input text
dns_master_load: /etc/bind/mcduckcorp.db:16: www.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali: CNAME and other data
zone mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/mcduckcorp.db failed: extra input text
zone mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali/IN: not loaded due to errors
```

duckburg.db:

```
dns_master_load: /etc/bind/duckburg.db:1: extra input text
zone duckburg.cali/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/duckburg.db failed: extra input text
zone duckburg.cali/IN: not loaded due to errors
```

cali.db

```
dns_master_load: /etc/bind/cali.db:1: extra input text
zone cali/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/cali.db failed: extra input text
zone cali/IN: not loaded due to errors
```

And here are the configuration-files:

mcduckcorp.db:

```
$TTL 30 d
$ORIGIN mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali. 
@ IN SOA ns1.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali. mail.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali. (
            2019092700 ;serial
            86400 ;refresh
            7200 ;retry
            3600000 ;expiration
            172800) ;minimum

@ IN NS ns1.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.
ns1.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.   IN   A   192.168.1.10
mail.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.  IN   A   192.168.1.10
www.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.   IN   A   192.168.1.10

www   IN   CNAME   squirrel
```

duckburg.db:

```
$TTL 30 d
$ORIGIN duckburg.cali.
@ IN SOA ns1.duckburg.cali. mail.duckburg.cali. (
                        2019092700 ;serial
                        86400 ;refresh
                        7200 ;retry
                        3600000 ;expiration
                        172800) ;minimum

@ IN NS ns1.duckburg.cali.
ns1.duckburg.cali.              IN   A   192.168.1.10
mail.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.  IN   A   192.168.1.10
www.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.   IN   A   192.168.1.10

subdomain   IN   NS   ns1.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.
ns1.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.   IN   A   192.168.1.10

www   IN   CNAME   squirrel
```

cali.db:

```
$TTL 30 d
$ORIGIN cali.
@ IN SOA ns1.cali. mail.cali. (
                        201909700 ;serial
                        86400 ;refresh
                        7200 ;retry
                        3600000 ;expiration
                        172800) ;minimum

@ IN NS ns1.cali.
ns1.cali.                       IN   A   192.168.1.10
mail.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.  IN   A   192.168.1.10
www.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.   IN   A   192.168.1.10

subdomain   IN   NS   ns1.duckburg.cali.
ns1.duckburg.cali.              IN   A   192.168.1.10

www   IN   CNAME   squirrel
```

I've obviously made a (or a few) mistakes but I'm not sure what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Christopher I doubt there would be a registrar involved in a school assignment.

Comment: there should not be a space between the `30` and the `d` on the `$TTL` lines.

Comment: also, in `mcduckcorp.db` you first define `www.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.` as an A record with IP address 192.168.1.10.  Later you define it as a CNAME pointing to `squirrel.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali.`.    a CNAME record can **not** have any other record types - not an A or MX or NS or anything else.  A CNAME is an alias pointing to another domain name, and **ALL** of the info is defined by the record it is an alias for.

Comment: btw, you should never use a domain you don't own. even in examples.  use subdomains of example.org, example.com, example.net - they are guaranteed never to be assigned to anyone and can safely be used for examples, assignments, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I'm gonna try your solutions asap!

Comment: @cas if we're not going to find the dup of this question - and I'm sure there must be one - then might I recommend you put your comment in an answer?

Comment: i might do that in the morning (it's 1.30am here).  btw, my comments are always free to steal into an answer if you or anyone else wants to write one.  comments are fair game on SE sites.

Comment: @cas Thanks again for the answers. I'm a bit confused though about the CNAME and www part. I'm supposed to add an A record to "www.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali" and then create a CNAME record for www it seems like.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record.    i'd suggest either adding an A record for mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali and then make www a CNAME pointing to it.   or an A record for www, and then make squirrel a CNAME pointing to www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few obvious problems with your zone files:

1. You should never use domains that don't belong to you, even for examples and assignments.  They may not exist now, but they may do in future.

   Use `example.org`, `example.com`, `example.net` for examples and homework assignments etc.  These domains are guaranteed never to be allocated to anyone and are safe to use by anyone.  The exist for precisely this purpose.
2. There should not be a space between the `30` and the `d` on the `$TTL` lines.
3. in `mcduckcorp.db` you first define `www.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali`. as an A record with IP address 192.168.1.10.

   Later you define it as a CNAME pointing to `squirrel.mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali`.  This can't work.

   A [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) defines an alias pointing to another domain name.  The record looks like:

   ```
   alias-name IN CNAME canonical-name
   ```

   The alias-name can not have any other data records, not `A` or `MX` or `NS` or anything else - it's just an alias pointing somewhere else (to the canonical-name).  In other words, the alias "inherits" **all** the data of the name it points to, and can not modify it in any way (no additions, deletions, or edits).

Your assignment requires you to show examples of A records and CNAME records. Try making an A record for the domain itself and then making `www` an alias pointing to it.  e.g.

```
    @   IN A     192.168.1.10
    www IN CNAME @
```

`www` would "inherit" all the records associated with `@` (the $ORIGIN, the domain itself). That includes the A record, and any NS or MX or TXT and whatever other records might exist.

An NS record is mostly irrelevant here, but an MX record can be useful if, e.g., the mail server for `domain.example.com` is configured to also handle mail for `www.domain.example.com`.

Alternatively, you could make an A record for `www`, and then make `squirrel` an alias pointing to that.  e.g.

```
    www      IN A     192.168.1.10
    squirrel IN CNAME www
```

Here, squirrel inherits everything from `www`, which only has an A record.

Comment: It seems to work now without any errors! I really appreciate your help! I'm gonna point it out to my teacher about using another domain too :)